# ldapsearch filter to get list of usernames

Tags: recursion, active-directory, ldap

I have an Active Directory 2012 server and openldap-client v2.4 installed on a CentOS 6.6 machine.

This is my hierarchy of users.

```
Syd-Users
   |
   |
   |-- SP Admins (a security group)
                |
                |
                |-- GU Admins  (a security group with multiple groups and users)
                |-- Vikas Kumar (a user)
```

I am trying to do a recursive search so that all "usernames" under a particular security group "SP Admins" can be listed out recursively.

```
# ldapsearch -x -h mydc.harris.syd -D "CN=Bind,OU=Syd-Users,DC=harris,DC=syd" -w 'password' -b "CN=SP Admins,OU=Syd-Users,DC=harris,DC=syd" -s sub "(&(objectClass=*))" | grep ^member
member: CN=GU Admins,OU=Syd-Users,DC=harris,DC=syd
member: CN=Vikas Kumar,OU=Aus,OU=Syd-Users,DC=harris,DC=syd
#
```

I have tried few filters like below in vain.

```
(&(sAMAccountName=*)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=SP Admins,OU=Syd-Users,DC=harris,DC=syd))
(&(objectClass=*)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=SP Admins,OU=Syd-Users,DC=harris,DC=syd))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People who are stuck in writing filters should use [Active Directory Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/bb963907.aspx). It is not very user friendly but extremely useful to create and test filters.

I could not create a filter for recursive search, but used another security group which had all the users which I wanted to list. [This](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gads/admin/ldap.5.4.html) link was also helpful to figure what attributes I needed.

After numerous hit and trials, I came up with below filter to get the list of **sAMAccountName** of **Enabled** user accounts.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(sAMAccountName=*)(!userAccountControl=2)(memberOf=CN=AU Admins,OU=Syd-Users,DC=harris,DC=syd))
```

Hope this helps someone. Thanks.